# Check connectivity from one server to another server using Powershell or CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I wanted check connectivity status between two servers using Powershell or CMD.

One Server to another server connectivity check with Port number.

Comment: It is not clear where you intend to run this from... a 3rd independent server or from the source server in the question

Comment: That's [Test-NetConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps)!

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh Can you add that as an answer. Since that still does not exist yet as one and sounds the most PowerShelly assuming that is is in ps3 /4 per the tags in the question

Comment: @Matt 
From 3rd independent server

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient -ArgumentList Server01, 3389
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Test-NetConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps) cmdlet:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName ServerName -Port 666
```

Comment: Is that PS6 or something? I have 5 and I do not have a port parameter. I do not see this list on TechNet either https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-6. Test-NetConnection maybe?

Comment: Yep. Muscle memory made me type Test-Connection instead of Test-NetConnection. Thanks Vivek.

Comment: Anytime sir! :)